# xlwings - find a cell coordinate containing a value(a date)

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have an excel sheet which contains calculations using formulas. It been manually updated each month but basically I working towards automating it. I have read a lot on how to use openpyxl but I wanted to read values not formulas which is why i found xlwings. Now I finding difficulty in finding coordintes of cell in xlwings. Its pretty straightforward in openpyxl cell.coordinate and want something similar to that.

I am pretty new to python so plz dont mind my syntax.

I have read the excel sheet into sheet1 variable and I am just trying to find the date in the first 50X50 matrix in the sheet.

This is the for loop:

```
for row in range(50):
   for col in range(50):
      if sheet1.range(row,col).value == '12/1/2017':
         print ((row,col))
```

Now I know .value in xlwings returns datetime and I am comparing it to a date and I found the workaround using something from the this -->http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html

```
import datetime as dt
sht.range('A1').options(dates=dt.date).value
```

But I am not getting how should I implement it.

At the end I am getting the error

```
return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(*allArgs),self._olerepr_.defaultDispatchName,None)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

This error doesnt seem to be related to what I think I am doing, but i cant seem to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you want to find the coordinates of a cell with a specific text...
I've done this:

```
for row in range(1, 10):
    for col in range(1, 10):
        if sht.range((row,col)).value == "TEXT":
            print("The Row is: "+str(row)+" and the column is "+str(col))
```

I hope I've helped you